# Sorting Data With Distinct in Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sorting, distinct

I created a game and I want to store user's high scores.

For example, I have a table named `scores` with these records...

```
ID   | Name        | Score
1    | Grace       | 90
2    | Grace       | 100
3    | Ben         | 70
4    | Kim         | 80
5    | Grace       | 74
6    | Grace       | 50
7    | Ben         | 80
8    | Honey       | 23
9    | Babe        | 85
10   | Ben         | 120
```

I want to display the names of player (without duplicates) and sorted it from highest to lowest score.

I tried this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM scores ORDER BY Score DESC
```

But it doesn't work for all times. It gives me this output...

```
Grace
Babe
Kim
Ben
Honey
```

From the table, Ben has the highest score. From this output, Grace is the first one listed but she did not get the highest score.

What Sqlite code should I put so that it can display these expected output?

```
Ben
Grace
Babe
Kim
Honey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query sorts *all* rows by score first, then removes some random rows until no duplicates are left.

You have to get the largest score for each player before sorting:

```
SELECT Name,
       MAX(Score)
FROM scores
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY MAX(Score) DESC
```